# ASP.NET Web Application Administration Security section: Unable to connect to SQL Server DB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, administration

I am using SQL Server Web (Full version not SQLExpress). I can connect to the database fine from my VS2010. However when I go to ASP.NET Web Application Administration, click "Security" I got below error:

> *There is a problem with your selected
>   data store. This can be caused by an
>   invalid server name or credentials, or
>   by insufficient permission. It can
>   also be caused by the role manager
>   feature not being enabled. Click the
>   button below to be redirected to a
>   page where you can choose a new data
>   store.*

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database. "

I know I miss something. Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: did you run aspnet_regsql? did you configure the web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tip, have a look in your web.config file and set **YOURMACHINENAME** in the `data source`

```
<connectionStrings>
   <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
   <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=YOURMACHINENAME ;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Hope it help